# Direct Comparison need to find a series to compare, need assistance.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I am trying to use direct comparison test to prove if the following series converge or not. Limit comparison is easier but the directions in the book are to use direct comparison. 
$$ \large \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{5}{8 \sqrt n + 3 \sqrt[3] n }$$

Unfortunately I can only show, by comparing denominators, that the original series is strictly less than a series divergent by the p-series test. 
$$ \large \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{5}{8 \sqrt n + 3 \sqrt[3] n } <  \large \frac{5}{8} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt n } = \infty $$

Maybe there is a standard approach that I am missing.

Comment: hint: use that $3 \sqrt[3] n < 3 \sqrt n$ to show that the series diverge

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$ 8\sqrt{n}+3\sqrt[3]{n} < 11\sqrt{n} \implies \frac{1}{8\sqrt{n}+3\sqrt[3]{n}} > \ldots$$